# root element is already defined jaxb

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb2

My problem is that I have two Schemas A.xsd B.xsd

they both share the same root, I'm gonna try to exemplify

```
 A.xsd
 <xs:element name="A">
   <xs:complexType>
      .my elements on A
   </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

 B.xsd
 <xs:element name="A">
  <xs:complexType>
   .my elements on B
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

When I try to generate the classes the output is that element 'A' is Already defined. 
So I created a Binding file that defines to xsd A, creates for the element A a class C, and for xsd B creates for the element A a class D

```
 X.xjb
 <bindings schemaLocation="A.xsd">
  <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='A']">
   <class name="C">
  </bindings>
 </bindings>

 <bindings schemaLocation="B.xsd">
  <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='A']">
   <class name="D">
  </bindings>
 </bindings>
```

But didnt work, it outputs the same error, 'A' is Already defined, so I tried with property instead of class on the binding file.

```
 X.xjb
 <bindings schemaLocation="A.xsd">
  <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='A']">
   <property name="C">
  </bindings>
 </bindings>

 <bindings schemaLocation="B.xsd">
  <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='A']">
   <property name="D">
  </bindings>
 </bindings>
```

, didnt work either

They do not have a targetNamespace

Anyone ever did something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign them [to different Java packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html#wp148550) and you should be fine.

```
<jxb:schemaBindings>
    <jxb:package name="primer.myPo">
        <jxb:javadoc>
            <![CDATA[<body> Package level documentation for generated package primer.myPo.</body>]]>
        </jxb:javadoc>
    </jxb:package>
    <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
    </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
</jxb:schemaBindings>
```

Comment: @user2370372, can you please post the xjc command line or parameters, etc.?

Comment: sure, the arguments that I use are -npa and -b mybindingfile.xjb

Comment: @user2370372, you need to run xjc once for each XSD, each with its own binding file; in a single pass you cannot load XSDs that define global XSD components with the same name.

Comment: got it, I did like that, I was hoping that was not gonna be necessary, thanks for your time